# Delete a row using his index

Tags: jquery, row

this script simply creates a row with a function inside that should allow to delete it after. All works, but the alert sends only the -1 value as rowIndex.

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong, can you help me? Thanks in advance

```
function newRow(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    table.insertRow(1);
    var row = "<tr><td><input type='text'><img src='x.png' onClick='cancRow($(this).closest(\"table\").attr(\"id\"))'></td></tr>";
    table.rows[1].innerHTML = row;
}

function cancRow(tableID){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex();
    alert('tableID: ' + tableID + ' rowIndex: ' + rowIndex);
    //document.getElementById(tableID).deleteRow(rowIndex);
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<table id="abilitation">
  <tr>
    <td>Abilitations</td>
    <td><img src= "plus.png" onClick="newRow($(this).closest('table').attr('id'))"></td>
  </tr>                     
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in your function doesn't refer to the `img` it refers to the `window` object instead

to use the element which the event is attached to you need to send the `event` object in your function call, and then use `event.target` to get the desired element.

if you want to use JQuery:
you can use either `$(event.target).closest("tr").index()` 
or
`$(event.target).closest("tr").prop('rowIndex')` to get the row index

```js
function newRow(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    table.insertRow(1);
    var row = "<tr><td><input type='text'><img src='x.png' onClick='cancRow(event, $(this).closest(\"table\").attr(\"id\"))'></td></tr>";
    table.rows[1].innerHTML = row;
}

function cancRow(event, tableID){
    var row = event.target.closest("tr");
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex;
    alert('tableID: ' + tableID + ' rowIndex: ' + rowIndex);
    document.getElementById(tableID).deleteRow(rowIndex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"><img src="x.png" onClick="cancRow(event, $(this).closest('table').attr('id'))"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="newRow('my-table')">Add row</button>
```

Comment: Solved, thanks for the answer and the explanation man, i lost too much time on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr") ;
var rowIndex = row.index();
```

Note: Index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

kindly try out this.

Html:

```js
function newRow(tableID) {
  debugger
  var table = $("#" + tableID + " tbody")
  var row = "<tr><td><input type='text'><img src='x.png' onClick='cancRow($(this).closest(\"table\").attr(\"id\"))'></td></tr>";
  table.append(row);
  //table.rows[1].innerHTML = row;

}


function cancRow(tableID) {
  debugger;
  var row = $("#" + tableID + " tbody").closest("tr");
  var rowIndex = $("#" + tableID + " tbody").find('tr').parent().index();
//for last index;  
 //$("#" + tableID + " tbody").find('tr').last().index();
  alert('tableID: ' + tableID + ' rowIndex: ' + rowIndex);
  //document.getElementById(tableID).deleteRow(rowIndex);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1">
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="newRow('t1')">new</button>
<button onclick="cancRow('t1')">del</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried, but now the result of rowIndex is alway 0

Comment: you need a last index of tr?

Comment: if you need last index try this  $("#" + tableID + " tbody").find('tr').last().index();